# Creating pop-up box if condition is true in table using ArcPy with ArcMap

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.0

I'm creating a script that will grab layout data from a table for the current Building Number of the current building my map series is on. It works fine, but I need it to pop up a window if multiple entries exist in the table for that same Building Number. In this window I would need to be able to choose one of the entries identified by their BLDNAME attribute.

Is this possible with ArcPy?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Alert boxes in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177287/alert-boxes-in-python) at Stack Overflow provides a solution:

```
import win32api

win32api.MessageBox(0, 'hello', 'title')
```

Additionally:

```
win32api.MessageBox(0, 'hello', 'title', 0x00001000)
```

will make the box appear on top of other windows, for urgent messages. See [MessageBox function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505(v=vs.85).aspx) for other options.